# Solr boost query by field value and inside newest date

Tags: sorting, solr, lucene, relevance, solr-boost

We have the following setup in our schema.xml:

```
<field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"/>
...

<field name="prefix" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"/>
```

Our goal is to sort the docs by

1. prefix=9999 with newest docs (last modified) first
2. prefix=1004 or prefix=1005 with newest docs (last modified) first

Our code:

```
{!boost b=recip(ms(NOW,last_modified),3.16e11,1,1)}prefix:9999^1000000 OR {!boost b=recip(ms(NOW,last_modified),3.16e-11,1,1)}prefix:1004^600000 OR {!boost b=recip(ms(NOW,last_modified),3.16e-11,1,1)}prefix:1005^600000
```

Result:
The query above does not work as expected!

We thought that omitTermFreqAndPositions=true will force to prevent ITF and the scoring should work. But it does not seem so!
Please help us with this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we found a solution!

1. Create your own Similarity (a simple java class)
   For a better and simpler descriptions how, please read [How to compile a custom similarity class for SOLR / Lucene using Eclipse](http://solrjack.blogspot.co.at/2013/07/how-to-compile-custom-similarity-class.html)

The class we used

```
package com.luxactive;
import org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInvertState;
import org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.DefaultSimilarity;

public class MyNewSimilarityClass  extends DefaultSimilarity {

@Override
public float coord(int overlap, int maxOverlap) {
    return 1.0f;
}

@Override
public float idf(long docFreq, long numDocs) {
    return 1.0f;
}

@Override
public float lengthNorm(FieldInvertState arg0) {
    return 1.0f;
}

@Override
public float tf(float freq) {
    return 1.0f;
}

}
```

2. Create a simple jar with your Similarity
3. Copy the jar to any folder into your solr server, we used:
   `SOLRFOLDER/solr-4.8.0/example/solr/dih`

The next steps need to be done to **every collection** you have!

4. Edit the solrconfig.xml at: `SOLRFOLDER/solr-4.8.0/example/solr/collection/conf/solrconfig.xml` 
   Add `<lib dir="../dih" regex=".*\.jar" />` to import the custom jar
5. Edit the schema.xml in the same folder

Add the following

```
<!-- DEFAULT Factory for custom com.luxactive.MyNewSimilarityClass  -->
<similarity class="solr.SchemaSimilarityFactory"/>

<!-- TYPE String -->
 <fieldType name="no_term_frequency_string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" >
    <similarity class="com.luxactive.MyNewSimilarityClass"/>
</fieldType>

<!-- TYPE Date -->
<fieldType name="no_term_frequency_date" class="solr.TrieDateField" sortMissingLast="true" >
    <similarity class="com.luxactive.MyNewSimilarityClass"/>
</fieldType>

<!-- TYPE Int-->
<fieldType name="no_term_frequency_int" class="solr.TrieIntField" sortMissingLast="true" >
    <similarity class="com.luxactive.MyNewSimilarityClass"/>
</fieldType>
```

Here you define your own field types (int, string and date) that use the new Similarity class which will return a boost value like defined in the MyNewSimilarityClass.

6. Now edit the fields you want to use your custom Similaritry by setting theyr type to one you created.
   From: `<field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />`
   To: `<field name="last_modified" type="no_term_frequency_date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />`
7. Restart the solr server and enjoy your boosting :)